# Best practices for logging in Python in shared libraries

Tags: python, logging, dependency-management

In a nutshell, I write ETL pipelines. They are usually described in high-level scripts. In them, I use different internal libraries (we manage them) that provide utility functions, tooling or internal data structure.

What are the common best practices about logging when dealing with multiple packages import from different repositories?

My questions are:

1) Should I put logs in libraries? Or only in top-level scripts?

On one hand, It could be useful to display some information in some library functions/classes. On the other hand, it imposes the library client usage of a particular logger.

I checked a few open-source projects and it seems that there are no logs at all.

2) If we indeed put logs in all shared libraries, what is the best practices in Python to pass a unique logger to everything?

I want my logging format and strategy to be consistent in each library call as everything is run as part "as a whole". Should I init my logger in the main script and pass the same logger in every object I create? It seems redundant to me. I saw another pattern where all classes that need logging would inherit from a logging class. It seems to me that it might overkill and complicates the overall architecture.

I read in another stackoverflow that *Actually every logger is a child of the parent's package logger*. How to apply that when the packages come different repositories?

thanks

Comment: not a good idea to put the log in the core library, just in the main script where you have called the core library package, you can add log

Comment: @prashantrana Why is that not a good idea? Even standard lib packages, such as multiprocessing, [set up](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.8/Lib/multiprocessing/util.py#L28-L103) and [use](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.8/Lib/multiprocessing/pool.py?highlight=debug#L140) logging, so that a developer can chose to activate it, without having to mess around in modules they don't own.

Comment: See [Configuring Logging for a Library](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/logging.html#configuring-logging-for-a-library) from the stdlib docs.

Comment: @shmee by core library i mean, suppose you are using tensorflow or pandas and you know that they are working fine and do their task, you don't need to add logs inside that core library that data flow happening inside it like abc, what you do is the point in code where you use those library /function, you log at that moment , as `logging.info`('passing data to xyz func') ` something like this

Comment: [this](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/165650/rules-and-advice-for-logging) provides  good practices in general , it is not python-specific, but should be good to regard these principles when designing logging system.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add a logger with no handlers (or with just the [null handler](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/logging.handlers.html#nullhandler)) to the library and do all the internal logging with that. Give it a name that is related to the library. When you do that any app that uses the lib can get the logger and add a handler to access the logs as needed.

An example would be the requests library which does something similar to that.

```
import logging
import requests
r = logging.getLogger('requests')
r.addHandler(logging.StreamHandler())
r.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
requests.get('http://stackoverflow.com')
```

will print

```
Starting new HTTP connection (1): stackoverflow.com
http://stackoverflow.com:80 "GET / HTTP/1.1" 301 143
Starting new HTTPS connection (1): stackoverflow.com
https://stackoverflow.com:443 "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 23886
```